# Sitefinity 7.0 multisite dynamic module related media (Image) not working for second site

Tags: sitefinity

I have converted a single site to a multisite in Sitefinity 7.0.

I have got a dynamic module with a related media (image) field called "Thumbnail."

I have selected images for the Thumbnail field in the content for both of the sites, but I am getting the image only on the original site (i.e. only on Site A and not on Site B).

I am using `obj.GetValue<Image>("Thumbnail")` to get the value from the dynamic object.

I am getting `null` for Site B.

[image]

I am having the same issue for the `SmallThumbnail` field as well.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [GetRelatedItems](https://docs.sitefinity.com/example-retrieve-item-relations) extension method for any related data/media.

Also, you've probably hit this [RELATED MEDIA FIELD NOT SHARED IN MULTISITE](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Related-media-field-not-shared-in-multisite)

Comment: `GetRelatedItems` works only on Site A and not on Site B, same as `GetValue`.

Comment: Updated my answer above

Comment: I have upgraded Sitefinity version from version 7.0 to 7.3.5681. This doesn't fix the issue.  I added a new field(of type image) with "default site source" provider after upgrading the Sitefinity, still having the same problem. We have lots of Dynamic modules in our multisite, all have same problem for RelatedMedia/Image fields.